# Make UITableView selection before view appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I'm building a detail view for a UITableView. The detail view contains a UITableView which has two rows, and I want the first one to be selected when the detail view is opened. I have tried to use the method `[selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition]` in `[viewWillAppear]`:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {  
    [[self tableView] selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:kStartDateRow inSection:kSection]  
                                  animated:NO  
                            scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];  
}
```

However, the selection is not affected by this, and using it in `[viewDidAppear]` means the selection changes once the view has moved into place. How can I make the selection before the detail view appears on screen?

You can see an example of the behaviour I want in the Settings app. Go to General > Date & Time > Set Date & Time.

Comment: Please show the code you tried in viewWillAppear and what error you get if any.

Comment: There you go. Had trouble with the code formatting, I hope it's readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention any error but try doing [[self tableView] reloadData] before the selectRowAtIndexPath line.

Comment: That totally worked! Thanks for the answer, but I'm puzzled as to why it worked.

Comment: In this case, it seems the tableView doesn't get around to calling reloadData itself until after viewWillAppear.  This: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html and this: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH5-SW1 might help to understand.