# How do I initialize a UITableView in the middle of the table

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

How can I initialize a UITableView so that it starts off showing something (of my choosing) in the middle of the table, rather than what is at the top?  I want to have a certain cell in the table always start at the top of the screen, so you could scroll up or down from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can scroll to a certain cell by sending [`- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath%3aatScrollPosition%3aanimated%3a) to the table view.

As you have described you want the cell of your choosing to appear "in the middle of the table", so you should use `UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle` for the scrollPosition argument.

If you do this as soon right after your table is initialized or as soon as your view loads with the animated argument set to `NO` then the table view will appear with your cell in the middle, just as you've described.

---

You also write: "I want to have a certain cell in the table always start at the top of the screen".

By instead choosing that cell and the scrollPosition `UITableViewScrollPositionTop` you can make that cell be at the top of your table view.

Comment: thanks, this works for scrolling the view to where I want it.  I want the table view to load in with a certain cell in the middle as well.  I tried putting this in viewDidLoad but that didn't accopmlish anything, it still loads with the table starting at the top. Do you know how to deal with this?

Comment: perhaps I'm doing this wrong, as I put it in the viewDidLoad of the containing view, not of the table view itself.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2934445/526433) - you need to reloadData and scroll in your viewWillAppear.